# Is it wiser to hedge downside risk with put options on an ETF, or Leveraged ETF, of the same index?

Tags: hedging

#### My pre-suppositions

1. I must hedge against a POSSIBLE market crash. But I can't predict if and when.
2. I hold no beliefs on volatility.
3. Small caps crash faster than large caps.

#### My question

I plan to spend $5000 USD —  that I CAN afford to lose —  to [buy OTM](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/91276) LEAPS put options on the Russell 2000 Index. What are the pros and cons of buying put options on ***IWM (iShares Core S&P Small-Cap ETF)* vs. leveraged ETFs** like

[RWM](https://www.proshares.com/funds/rwm.html) —  Short Russell2000
[TWM](https://www.proshares.com/funds/twm.html) —  UltraShort Russell2000
[SRTY](https://www.proshares.com/funds/srty.html) — UltraPro Short Russell2000
or [TZA](https://www.direxion.com/product/daily-small-cap-bull-bear-3x-etfs) —  Direxion Daily Small Cap Bear 3X ETF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inverse ETF isn't a good solution as it's very path dependent.   The market can wind up down 10% a year from now and you will find that you have lost money on the inverse ETF.   That's because the leveraged ETFs are geared to daily movements and you are looking at the longer term.  If you just want to hedge for a few hours (less than a day) then the leveraged ETFs are perfect.

Given that you don't want to make a vol bet and don't really want to pay the premium for that - your best option is a high delta put.   But the 80 delta put and it's basically like getting the short stock.   Then you can get great liquidity on the IWM puts and you will be good.